# Is there a way to buffer and page request flow in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to control the flow of requests coming into the ServiceStack host. I'm looking for something like [Observable.Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229813%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in reactive extensions, or a way to page up requests into buffers, or a place to implement something like this in the message flow. Mainly to handle traffic floods and spikes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Messaging support in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis). There are Redis and In Memory MQ Hosts that allow you to defer execution of incoming requests.

Once you have registered an `IMessageFactory` all calls to the `/async` one-way endpoints are [immediately deferred to your registered MQ Broker](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/ServiceRunner.cs#L165).

The SMessage demo project shows an example of [manually creating and publishing request dtos](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/Reusability/SMessageService.cs#L77) vs executing them synchronously in the same service.

Once the message handlers for all messages you want your MQ broker to handle are registered, e.g:

```
mqService.RegisterHandler<PostStatusTwitter>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads:2);
mqService.RegisterHandler<CallFacebook>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
mqService.RegisterHandler<EmailMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
```

Any Request DTO published will automatically queue in the MQ Broker queue and be processed in the background as fast as they can with as many background threads you specify.

Note: deferred requests are no longer in the HTTP Context so you lose access to HTTP params like Custom HTTP Headers.

Comment: Dose that mean that there is no way to do this without mq? Is there a way to hook how the HttpListener in HttpListenerBase gets used?

Comment: The [InMemoryTransientMessageService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Messaging) is entirely in-memory so doesn't require any external MQ Broker.

Comment: That looks more promising, and I like that you can just fork lift it when you need to expand to an actual process. You mentioned that you loose the http context once you defer the message, but I'm assuming the http session remains active? otherwise how would you return data to the requestor?

Comment: Nope, no cookies exist required by the Session either. [Request filters don't get executed for MQ Requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview) either. MQ requests are effectively internal requests, I I recommend validating the request against the session before deferring the request, otherwise add an explicit **SessionId** property on the DTO and retrieve the Session manually with `Cache.GetSession(ssId)` extension method.